# Switching bluetooth headphones mode at certain short intervals

Tags: windows, windows-10, bluetooth

I connect bluetooth headphones and constantly changes the connection status from "voice connected" to "voice, music connected" at short intervals. With this work in the headphones does not play anything, Also increases the load on the CPU up to 20%. Video - https://ru.files.fm/u/tuttvfzh9

What I did in an attempt to solve the problem:

- uninstalled, reinstalled bluetooth module drivers (via computer search)
- changed the Bluetooth audio gateway service logon to Local service

Tried with the following headphones:

Remax RB-500HB

AirPods 2

The situation does not change